# Copy shared subdirectories into a new directory

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two directories. One of them contains ~50,000 folders, the other containings ~10,000. I'd like to see which folder names are common to **both** directories, and then to move those folders (and their contents) from directory1 into a third directory, directory3.

Below is what I have written - however, I get the error `IOError: [Errno 21] Is a directory`

Can anyone point out how to improve what im doing wrong?

```
import os,sys,time,shutil

#specify root directories,
rootdir1 = "/Directory1"
rootdir2 = "/Directory2"
rootdir1_folders = []
rootdir2_folders = []


#Go through first directory, make list of names of folders in that directory
for subdir, dirs,files in os.walk(rootdir1):
        if("GeneSet" in subdir):
            folder_name = subdir.rsplit('/', 1)[-1]
            rootdir1_folders.append(folder_name)

#Go through second directory, make list of names of folders in that directory
for subdir, dirs,files in os.walk(rootdir2):
        if("GeneSet" in subdir):
            folder_name = subdir.rsplit('/', 1)[-1]
            rootdir2_folders.append(folder_name)

#check which folders are in both directories. 
intersected_list = list(set(rootdir1_folders).intersection(rootdir2_folders))

#move folders from first rootdir to the new folder
for subdir, dirs,files in os.walk(rootdir1):
        if("GeneSet" in subdir):
            new_folder=subdir.rsplit('/', 1)[-1]
            if(new_folder in intersected_list):
               shutil.copy(subdir,"directory3")
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./FILE_NAME_COMPARER.py", line 41, in <module>
    shutil.copy(subdir, "directory3")
  File "/home/unix/sgerges/.conda/envs/ldsc/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 133, in copy
    copyfile(src, dst)
  File "/home/unix/sgerges/.conda/envs/ldsc/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 96, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
IOError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/directory1/CB_3.2_versus_FC_1.8_GeneSet'
```

Comment: Could you list your traceback? It would be helpful to see which line it is failing on. Thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] to show the full traceback. *What* is a directory?

Comment: I added traceback. Each directory simply contains a list of subdirectories, if that answers your question?

Comment: please take a look at the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copy) the first argument to `shutil.copy` should be a file not a directory, however you are providing a directory since the first result returned by `os.walk` is the `dirpath`

Answer (score 2):

`shutil.copy()` can only copy individual files. You want [`shutil.copytree()`.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copytree)

Comment: I just get the error ```OSError: [Errno 17] File exists: ```